# Conditional tag based on the role of author in author.php

Tags: user-roles, author-template

Is there any way to display different data in an `author.php` profile template depending on the role of the profile displayed? (NOT of the person viewing it, but the author that particular profile refers to).

If a profile is being displayed of an author with role `editor`, then some content would be displayed, and if the profile belongs to an author with role `contributor`, then some other stuff would be displayed.

I haven't found an answer for this anywhere yet. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`current_user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) does not give the desired output when working with roles. There is a [trac ticket #22624](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624) explaining this all. It was closed with the following

> - Keywords close removed
> - Milestone Awaiting Review deleted
> - Resolution set to wontfix
> - Status changed from new to closed

My solution would be to get the role of the featured user and then check that against the specific [roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Roles)

The first thing would be to retrieve the author's role with `get_queried_object()->roles` and then check of the desired role is in array, and if it is, do something. Here is the code

```
$user_role = get_queried_object()->roles[0];

if( in_array( strtolower('Editor'), $user_role ) ) {
    //Do something for Editor
}elseif( in_array( strtolower('Contributor'), $user_role ) ) { 
    //Do something for Contributor
}
```

**EDIT**

User roles starts with uppercase letters, but the roles returned from `get_queried_object()->roles` starts with lowercase letters. That is why I've use the roles as such in my code and used `strtolower` to convert the roles to lowercase

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Works wonderfully.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work...
`<?php $user_role = get_queried_object()->roles; ?>
<?php if( in_array( strtolower('Teacher'), $user_role ) ) { ?>
 teacher
<?php } elseif( in_array( strtolower('School'), $user_role ) ) { ?>
 school
<?php } ?>`

Comment: @Pete There is a slight error, I have fixed it in my code, `get_queried_object()->roles` returns an array, so you should access the first value with `get_queried_object()->roles[0]`

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be done?

Sure.

Inside `author.php` get the user id who viewed profile refers to, using [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/a-specific-role) check the capability and finally conditionally display content based on that.

I said "check the capability" and not "check the role" because check roles is a *meh* thing, it's a lot better and recommended check for capabilities. Use [`user_can`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/user_can/) for the scope.

Comment: Unless you have 3 roles with exactly the same capabilities, but you need them to be named differently and query them separately, in which case, your answer is of no use, and Pieter's works perfectly.

Comment: I stand corrected. Apologies, and thanks. Duly noted.